# debounceTime & distinctUntilChanged in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I found some tutorial in rxjs that uses debounce and distinctUntilChanged. How can I implement it in angular 6?

The tutorial code is this:

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input,'input');

observable.map(event=>event.target.value)
    .debounceTime(2000)
    .subscribe({
        next:function(value){
        console.log(value)
    }
}
```

This is my code:

In html, I have this:

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userQuestion" type="text" name="userQuestion" id="userQuestions">
```

in Typescript, I have this:

```
import { Subject,Observable } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime,distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";

ngOnInit() {
    // initialization
    this.userQuestion = new Observable;
    this.userQuestion.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000)).subscribe(val => {
            console.log(val)
        }
    )
}
```

It doesnt work. How can I make it work?

Comment: It does not work is a meaningless statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to be mindful of:

In the typescript you are not initialising your Observable properly. You should use the 'fromEvent' convenience method if you want to generate an Observable based on a DOM event (e.g. 'input')

Secondly, `pipe` is just used to wrap around any operators. So a subscribe shouldn't be used within `pipe`

### EDIT

You must create the Observable in ngAfterViewInit if you're using @ViewChild. ViewChild won't be accessible before that point.

In your template

```
<input #questionInput class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userQuestion" type="text" name="userQuestion" id="userQuestions">
```

In .ts

```
@ViewChild('questionInput') questionInput: ElementRef;

public input$: Observable<string>;

////
  ...code...
////

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.input$ = fromEvent(this.questionInput.nativeElement, 'input');
      .pipe(
         debounceTime(2000),
         map((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.target['value'])
      );

     this.input$.subscribe((val: string) => {
         console.log(val)
      });
}
```

Comment: There are errors. first, in variable this.input$, the error is Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>' Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
Second. questionInput does not exist on type TestingComponent

Comment: I've edited my answer to correctly assign inuput$. Make sure that you have added the template reference in your HTML in order for the ElementRef to be found