# Using ngModelChange to update array of input fields

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use `ngModelChange` to update the underlying data for an array of input fields, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-ngfor?file=app%2Fexample.ts)

However, when the `ngModelChange` function is triggered, updating the underlying data model prevents further data entry (e.g. try typing `123` in any field, and you will see only the first digit is accepted until you click the field again).

This kind of scenario (`ngFor` bound to array of fields) works easily with `angular 2` way data binding, however, I need it to work with one-way-binding + `ngModelChange` so that I can do other things besides just updating the underlying data (e.g. as shown in the stackblitz, I trigger `unsavedChanges` flag to display a warning in the UI).

Any ideas how to make this work?

Note: I already explored S.O. for articles on `ngModelChange` / `debounceTime` e.g. [ngModelChange / debounceTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780025/debouncetime-in-angular6-ngmodelchange/51787602)

Based on those articles, I can see how using a `Subject` to push (debounced) changes in the `ngModelChange` function could work easily for single / static fields. However, in my scenario I have a dynamic array collection, and am not sure if I need to go down the route of an array of `Subjects` or a single `Subject` which contains an Array, or else if there's a more trivial solution to this whole problem (e.g. use 2 way binding but trigger another function somehow).

Any help greatly appreciated!

- S. Arora

Answer (score 1):

After further experimentation I found that debouncing changes to the data model still didn't solve the data entry issue, and that the real issue was the input field was losing focus after each change.

Apparently it's a known issue that you need to use a trackBy function when using an array of primitives, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322968/angular2-dynamic-input-field-lose-focus-when-input-changes)