# Angular - How to capture text-area to get its content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component where there is a textarea. I need to capture a value change in the textarea, then send it to server as PUT request(update). I do not want to update the value on text area lost focus, but rather a auto-save function.

I have seen several articles showing auto-save to the entire form. But I need to auto-save only this particular field's text content.

I came up with a code segment as below, but within it I need to capture the textarea (either by id or etc):

```
this.subs.add(this.INeedToCaptureFieldById
  .pipe(debounceTime(2000), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.updateContent();
  }));
```

How to capture the textarea in Angular, but couldnt figure a way. how to capture the textarea "INeedToCaptureFieldById"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture that via `ngModelChange` event like so:

**component.html**

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="valueVariable" (ngModelChange)="changed()"></textarea>
```

**component.ts**

```
valueVariable: string;

changed():any{
  console.log(this.valueVariable);
}
```

Comment: but for this event to trigger, textarea should loose focus right. I mean like we need to enter text and click somewhere else in the page. I need to autosave without lost-focus

Comment: See this working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-zwzqp4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) Iv'e created

Comment: thank you for this. Will it be possible to have a debounceTime (interval to resend) for this, rather than sending immediately ?

Comment: Yes you can, you will need to change it a bit, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780025/debouncetime-in-angular6-ngmodelchange)

Comment: I've changed the code - [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-zwzqp4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)